# Laravel Additional Attributes added to both models in many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to added created_at and updated_at in the pivot table(user_role) but I am not sure whether it is necessary to added withTimestamps() in both models (e.g users and roles) or add it to one of the models will do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in the relation of both model. If you only add it to your `App\User` model, then the timestamp will only be maintained when retrieving or updating via the user model.

You can read more about many to many relations here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many